# How to use variables in kickstart file for RHEL installation

Tags: centos, rhel

I would like to use an environment variable in a kickstarter file as in this example:

```
NFS_KICKSTART=12.23.12.23:12222
nfs --server=$NFS_KICKSTART --dir=/kickstart/

# do some post processing
mount -o nolock $NFS_KICKSTART:/kickstart/ /mnt/temp
```

Apparently the variables does not get expanded. How can I expand the variable to be used inside the kickstart file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on [stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115281/407841).First create a file in the `%pre` section and write that to `/tmp`. In there you can use environment variables as mentioned in the question.

Then use `%include` to include this file in the kickstarter file wherever required.